# Trying to 'git pull' from PHP script, running into SSH permissions problems

Tags: php, git, ssh

I'm stumped by this code, which works locally but not remotely.

`<?php shell_exec('/usr/bin/git pull ssh://my.git.server/git/test-theme /home/dsgit1/wp-content/themes/test-theme' 2>&1); ?>`

(It's eventually going to be part of a WordPress plugin, but since I'm not using any WordPress-specific stuff at this time it shouldn't matter.)

The above seems to work with http:// and https:// repos, but my repo is only available via SSH at this time.

I've created an SSH key pair so that no password is required.

When I run the script from the Web server with php-cgi, as the user who runs Web content, it works. (I added a call to 'exec whoami' to confirm I'm running as the correct user.)

```
putenv("PATH=/usr/bin:/bin");
print "Running as user: ";
passthru('whoami');
// then the above shell_exec()
```

When I run the the git pull code locally, all works as expected:

```
-bash-4.1$ /usr/bin/php-cgi /home/dsgit1/wp-content/plugins/test/pull.php
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.3.3
Content-type: text/html

Running as user: dsgit1
Cloning into '/home/dsgit1/wp-content/themes/test-theme'...
Checking connectivity... done
```

... and the repo gets pulled into the local folder, as you'd expect.

We use mod_suphp and a separate local user for each site, which is why you see "dsgit1" and not "httpd" or "apache". The code is intended to run as that specific local user.

When I run the script remotely (by entering its URL into a browser, or feeding it to wget) I get this:

```
Running as user: dsgit1
Cloning into '/home/dsgit1/wp-content/themes/test-theme'...
ssh: connect to host my.git.server port 22: Permission denied
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

It looks like, for some reason, when the code is run "remotely" it's not getting enough of the environment to read the SSH private key in ~/.ssh/id_rsa. The code is running as the same local user, so it should have read permissions on the SSH keys, but it can't or won't use them.

There's obviously some difference in how the code is run locally vs. remotely, but I have no idea what. Suggestions?

EDIT: /etc/suphp.conf, as requested by a commenter:

```
[global]
logfile=/var/log/httpd/suphp_log
loglevel=warn
webserver_user=apache
docroot=/
env_path=/bin:/usr/bin
umask=0022
min_uid=500
min_gid=500

; Security options
allow_file_group_writeable=true
allow_file_others_writeable=false
allow_directory_group_writeable=true
allow_directory_others_writeable=false

;Check wheter script is within DOCUMENT_ROOT
check_vhost_docroot=true

;Send minor error messages to browser
errors_to_browser=false
check_parent_owner=false

[handlers]
;Handler for php-scripts
; x-httpd-php=php:/usr/bin/php
x-httpd-php="php:/usr/bin/php-cgi"

;Handler for CGI-scripts
x-suphp-cgi=execute:!self
```

SECOND EDIT: Here's the output of a manual run, from the CLI, after changing my command to `$output = shell_exec('ssh -v gitreader@my.git.server pwd 2>&1');`

```
-bash-4.1$ /usr/bin/php-cgi ./wp-content/plugins/autogit/a4.php
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.3.3
Content-type: text/html

Running as user: dsgit1
<pre>OpenSSH_5.3p1, OpenSSL 1.0.0-fips 29 Mar 2010
debug1: Reading configuration data /home/dsgit1/.ssh/config
debug1: Applying options for my.git.server
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to my.git.server [172.20.60.96] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/dsgit1/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_5.3
debug1: match: OpenSSH_5.3 pat OpenSSH*
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_5.3
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REQUEST(1024<1024<8192) sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_GROUP
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_INIT sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REPLY
debug1: Host 'my.git.server' is known and matches the RSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/dsgit1/.ssh/known_hosts:3
debug1: ssh_rsa_verify: signature correct
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password,keyboard-interactive
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering public key: /home/dsgit1/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Server accepts key: pkalg ssh-rsa blen 277
debug1: read PEM private key done: type RSA
debug1: Authentication succeeded (publickey).
debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]
debug1: Requesting no-more-sessions@openssh.com
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug1: Sending environment.
debug1: Sending env LANG = en_US.UTF-8
debug1: Sending command: pwd
debug1: channel 0: forcing write
/home/gitreader
debug1: client_input_channel_req: channel 0 rtype exit-status reply 0
debug1: client_input_channel_req: channel 0 rtype eow@openssh.com reply 0
debug1: channel 0: free: client-session, nchannels 1
debug1: fd 1 clearing O_NONBLOCK
Transferred: sent 2288, received 2360 bytes, in 0.2 seconds
Bytes per second: sent 12073.1, received 12453.0
debug1: Exit status 0
</pre>
```

It logs in, runs one command and displays its output, then exits. The host already is in known_hosts, so no input is required.

Here's the output of the same thing, called from curl:

Running as user: dsgit1

```
OpenSSH_5.3p1, OpenSSL 1.0.0-fips 29 Mar 2010
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to my.git.server [172.20.60.96] port 22.
debug1: connect to address 172.20.60.96 port 22: Permission denied
ssh: connect to host my.git.server port 22: Permission denied
```

Comment: What permissions do you have on _~/.ssh/id_rsa_? `ls -l ~/.ssh/id_rsa` What group does your PHP run under? Also can you post your suPHP config?

Comment: The server is a RHEL one, so each user has its own group, identically named (user dsgit1, group dsgit1, in this case). id_rsa is mode 600, for that user: `-rw-------+ 1 dsgit1 dsgit1 1675 Dec  6 10:58 id_rsa`

Comment: Added /etc/suphp.conf to the question.

Comment: We know that ssh is failing. How about we remove git as a potential problem source. What happens if you do `<?php shell_exec('/usr/bin/ssh -T user@my.git.server 2>&1'); ?>`? Also if there is a "authenticity" user prompt during the connection the command will fail as `shell_exec` doesn't support user input.

Comment: You might also want to add the `-v` debug switch to help with the debugging. `<?php shell_exec('/usr/bin/ssh -v -T user@my.git.server 2>&1'); ?>`

Comment: Edited. I see that when I call it remotely, SSH isn't even looking at the user's home directory (the stuff in ~/.ssh). Unfortunately, fixing the problem for SSH may not fix it for Git, but it's a place to start.

Comment: I tried changing permissions on ~/.ssh/config and ~/.ssh/id_rsa to 660, no dice.

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered this kind of struggle when it comes to mod_suphp.  I am not fan of that apt and my scripts always call to check that mod_suphp is disable or uninstalled (which always solved the issue every time).

Comment: Unfortunately, that's probably not an option. We can't use straight mod_php because we have to run each site as a separate user (for policy reasons). Switching to mod_fcgid may not be feasible either, because it would require working on a production server with about 30 Web sites; it would be a hard argument to make the switch without a very good reason. (Honestly, the git/php/ssh thing here is not a good-enough reason; we may just abandon this little project rather than try to rebuild a whole server.)

Answer (score 0):

I think I've solved the root problem, but it ain't pretty.

I changed my command to a simple ssh command, and explicitly changed permissions on the relevant files in ~/.ssh to 660:

`shell_exec('ssh -v -F /home/dsgit1/.ssh/config gitreader@my.git.server pwd 2>&1')`

I still received "Permission denied" errors.

I found SELinux errors in my audit.log, and saw that the SELinux contexts are such that PHP processes cannot read the SSH files. (The files in ~/.ssh are all of type ssh_home_t.)

Disabling SELinux temporarily, and explicitly adding a -F to specify the configuration files to use, solved the problem for SSH. This should be extensible to Git with the GIT_SSH environment variable and a wrapper script, but requires leaving SELinux in permissive mode.

Creating a custom SELinux policy with this line should permanently resolve the issue while allowing me to leave SELinux enabled:

`allow httpd_t ssh_home_t:file read;`

There probably are plenty of other security implications to this, which my colleagues and I will discuss (and probably eventually decide are more important than accessing Git automatically via SSH).